# Reversing PE32 executable - CTF Question

Tags: disassembly

So we were playing CTF , and we found this interesting RE challenge . And when we did a statical analysis to the file we found an interesting for loop .

```
for (var_84 = 0x0; var_84 < 0x13; var_84 = var_84 + 0x1) {
       edx = var_84;
      *(int8_t * )(var_84 + "Catch Me If You Can") = sign_extend_32( * (int8_t * )(var_84 + "Catch Me If You Can")) ^ * (ebp + (edx * 0x4 - 0xd8));


}
```

Can anyone explain the code above ?

Answer (score 3):

It is byte-byte string xor in specific order.
"Catch me if you can" is a string, or array of bytes.

var_84 (and edx register) is an index in it.
I don't know what exactly is a stack layout and can not say with what exactly it is XORed.

In more readable C it will look like as follows:

```
array = &"Catch me if you can"[0];
for (var_84 = 0x0; var_84 < 0x13; var_84 = var_84 + 0x1) {
       edx = var_84;
      array[var_84] = sign_extend_32( array[var_84]) ^ * (ebp + (edx * 0x4 - 0xd8));

}
```